# How can I automatically check, that \baselineskip is large enough?

Tags: fonts, height, baseline

When I set a font size and baselineskip, I have to take care, that the baselineskip is large enough for my font. Is there an automatic way to check this in LaTeX?

Given the following example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\newcommand{\mine}{\sffamily\fontsize{14.7}{15.2}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,text=green,font=\mine](first) at (0,0){\strut Test/};
        \node[anchor=north west,font=\mine](first) at (0,0){\strut Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image]

As you can see the text is not perfectly sitting on top of each other, probably because the slash has more height.

Now if we take another font:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage{libertine}

\newcommand{\mine}{\sffamily\fontsize{14.7}{15.2}\selectfont}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[anchor=north west,text=green,font=\mine](first) at (0,0){\strut Test/};
        \node[anchor=north west,font=\mine](first) at (0,0){\strut Test};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and run it again, there is no bleeding:

[image]

If I increase the `\baselineskip` in the first example, the texts will also fit. So is there an automatic way to check that the baselineskip is large enough?

This issue is not about placement in TikZ, I know that I can avoid this issue altogether by using the `.* base` anchor for proper alignment, it is more about correct defintion of `\baselineskip`.

Comment: Why you need to manually alter the `\baselineskip`? What the origin of question/requirement?

Comment: An OpenType font has information about the font bounding box but not a tfm font for pdflatex, so you would need to set a box with all 256 characters in the font and then take the height and depth of the box.

Comment: The node texts in your first example does not perfectly overlap because 1) by default tikz uses `anchor=center`, hence put the center of node to coordinate `(0, 0)` 2) "Test/" has larger depth than "Test", hence the center of "Test/" is "lower".

Comment: With the calc package you can compare the `\totalheightof{...}` to `\baselineskip`, or `\heightof{...}` to `\ht\strutbox` and `\depthof{...}` to `\dp\strutbox`.

Comment: OTOH, if the font doesn't fit into an `\fbox` with `\fboxsep=0pt`, then you are just SOL.

Comment: The instruction `\fontsize{14.7}{15.2}` implies that the baseline skip is only ca 3.5% larger than the nominal font size. An overage of 20% is a far more common choice for serif and sans-serif fonts. Hence, do give `\fontsize{14.7}{17.6}`, or even `\fontsize{14.7}{18.4}` a try.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ There is no specific issue behind this question, it is more the wish to understand why certain things are like they are and in this case it is why can the baselineskip be enough for one font, but not enough for another.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle That is interesting, so TeX cannot know about this font attributes without testing and probing?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ 1) I define `anchor=north west`, so this issue is not an issue. 2) This is the issue I am referring to, but I thought from other answers, that `\strut` should be good for this purpose, because no matter what it will have the height and depth of the current baselineskip. However it seems that when needed, TeX can make more room for characters, than strut uses. So strut is not a perfect way to make Text aligned vertically e.g. on following slides in Beamer.

Comment: @JohnKormylo That would be the way to go for David‘s proposal to check all 256 chars. In this case also diacritics or other characters that could have more height would be taken into account.

Comment: @Mico of course this is a value I have just chosen to illustrate the problem. When I observed this behavior it was with a font that is not distributable and it happens with a baselineskip defined by a professional designer for the application of a design in PowerPoint. What I am after is that even though one font is fine with a particular baselineskip, another is not (like shown with CM and Libertine). So I am more interested to see how this could be solved in general, or if there is no general solution.

Comment: @TobiBS 1) anchor `north west` still relies on the actual total height of node, hence the issue doesn't disappear. But anchor `north` does not rely on text depth. 2) `\strut` always leaves a zero-width hbox with `0.7\baselineskip` height  and `0.3\baselineskip` depth in current font and current size. It is not good enough, if some higher or deeper character is used. And there is no assurance that a font will not contain those characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The misalignment in the image is not actually due to the baseline, as noted in comments.
(Unless you specify a width tikz nodes are like `\mbox` so no baseline calculation is used, only if you specify a width then they are `minipage` and so text specified baselines are used when breaking lines.

However for the main question, TFM fonts do not have any global parameter giving the font bounds so you need to calculate it.

Basically

```
\sbox0{ABC..xyz}
```

then `\dimexpr\ht0+\dp0`  is the vertical extent.

There is some flexibility in exactly what you put in the box to measure. You could use `\char0`...`\char255` so all the characters, but you may also want to consider constructed accents such as `\'{E}` which are probably not in the font, and also footnote markers such as `X\textsuperscript{\dagger}`  or whatever else you might reasonably expect to fit in a paragraph without disturbing the line spacing.